# reddit-omniauth gem getting " you sent an invalid request — invalid scope requested"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, omniauth, reddit

I am trying to implement reddit login in rails application using omniauth-reddit

---

login is succesfull but i don't no where its going wrong

[image]

> My  OmniauthCallbacksController.rb file

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def reddit_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    sign_in_and_redirect root_path
  end
```

> My User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:reddit]
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider,uid: auth.id).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.id = auth.id
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end
end
```

**`can anybody suggest me scope or solution ??` Thanks in Advance**

Comment: `# You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb`

Comment: Thank you !!!!!! but still getting same error